# Android Logging set verbose for all tags (logcat)

Tags: android, logging, android-logcat

I am debugging on device, and I do not get the verbose or debug log messages, only the info, warn, error and wtf. I need to get all debug and verbose messages, without enabling with setprop for all my tags (I am using different tags for each file). So how can I set device log level to VERBOSE globally? It is also good if you show me a java code from I can set log level for a tag - so my wrapper class will set log level for every new tag to verbose. But command line not good...